# How closely does the anime movie "In This Corner of the World" follow the manga?

Tags: in-this-corner-of-the-world

*In This Corner of the World* (*Kono Sekai no Katasumi*) anime movie was adapted from a manga of the same name. The manga has 48 chapters and the anime is about 2 hours and 6 mins long. However, I felt like some of the scenes were cut, or the flow of the story was disturbed and another scene was brought up so that the duration won't be too long.

I did read some chapters and found that the scene where Mizuhara drop Suzu's pencil in the hole was not in the anime. I want to read the manga if there are big changes or parts which affect the story.

Did the anime movie really follow the manga?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%93%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E3%81%AE%E7%89%87%E9%9A%85%E3%81%AB_(%E6%98%A0%E7%94%BB)#%E5%8E%9F%E4%BD%9C%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AE%E7%9B%B8%E9%81%95%E7%82%B9), the differences are (warning: also includes spoiler from the manga):

- The time period at the beginning of the story (year 1934 → year 1933)

  > At the beginning of the story, the time period of the episode when Little Suzu encountered the kidnapper on the way to deliver seaweed was advanced from "January 1934" to "December 1933". In the movie, after passing through various circumstances such as the reworking of the production plan, the time period of this episode was set in December 1933. In the movie, the state of the busy town in the Christmas shopping season is depicted. However, on that year, there was an event of the birth of the [Crown Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akihito) on December 23, the day before Christmas Eve, thus the celebratory mood should have continued from that day until the new year. Because of that, the episode at the beginning of the story was set sooner than that date.
- The emphasis on character relationships (Suzu-Keiko, Shusaku-Rin-Suzu, Teru-Rin-Suzu)

  > In the movie, the relationship contrast between Suzu as a wife and Keiko as a sister-in-law is the main point. The appearance of the courtesan Rin, a major character in the original was reduced, and an episode related to the love triangle between Shusaku, Rin, and Suzu is not shown. Along with this, the appearance of the courtesan Teru who mediates the reunion of Suzu and Rin in the original is cut to one scene only without any line. However, Teru is mentioned in Suzu's flashback and Suzu has possession of Teru's red cosmetic item, which Rin handed over to Suzu after Teru's death in the original.
- The scenes related to the characters' point-of-view

  > In the movie, the scenes from men's point-of-view like details of weapons such as ships and fighters, the feeling of male characters and more, were added, supplementing the women's point-of-view drawn in the original. During the beginning of the bombing of Kure (chapter 26 in the original), while Entaro is lying down protecting Suzu and Harumi, a dialog regarding his emotion to the [Homare engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakajima_Homare) mounted on [Kawanishi fighters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kawanishi_N1K) while dogfighting US fighters in the air was added. Also in this scene of the movie, when Suzu is fascinated by the sight of war, colorful bomb smoke is shown using paintbrush inside her imagination. While this was not shown in the original's monochrome, it's an arrangement based on the historical fact that coloring bullets for identification were mixed in the anti-aircraft guns of warships.
- Suzu's reaction to Japan's defeat

  > When Suzu flew out of the house raging after listening to [Jewel Voice Broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewel_Voice_Broadcast) reporting Japan's defeat, her line is changed when she looks at the raised [Taegukgi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_South_Korea) and breaks down crying. In chapter 38 of the original, Suzu feels that the justice they believed was lost and she talks to herself whether Japan will yield to violence since other countries have been conquered violently, while in the movie, her monologue is about whether they should yield to violence since they live on rice and soy coming from the other side of the sea. Regarding this, Katabuchi stated that Japan's food self-sufficiency at that time was not high and there were circumstances in which we had no choice but to rely on grain imported from abroad, and to talk about the same thing as the original, he said that he thought that it was better for Suzu to respond to food material since she is always doing the kitchen work. As a related depiction, when Suzu visits the black market, a random character refers to Taiwanese rice, a line not included in the original has been added.

---

Note: a 30-minute extended version of the movie, titled *In This Corner (and Other Corners) of the World* will be released on December 2018 (Source: [AnimeNewsNetwork](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2018-07-25/in-this-corner-of-the-world-anime-film-gets-extended-version-with-new-title/.134681)).

Comment: Very nice answer and good news about the movie